# L'Hospital's Rule; Find the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}[\ln(x^9 - 1) - \ln(x^5 - 1)]$

Tags: calculus, limits

Hello guys I'm having problem manipulating the equation into a form where I can use L'hospital rule. Can you help me?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}[\ln(x^9 - 1) - \ln(x^5 - 1)]$$

so far I've gotten up to here :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}{\ln\frac{(x^9 - 1)}{(x^5 - 1)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You're basically there.

$$ \ln \left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} \dfrac{x^9-1}{x^5-1} \right) $$

$$ \ln \left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} \dfrac{9x^8}{5x^4} \right)$$

$$ \ln \left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} \dfrac{9x^4}{5} \right) $$

$$ = \ln\left(\dfrac{9}{5}\right)$$

Comment: Whoops, lemme change that

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use L'hospitale rule for $\dfrac{x^9-1}{x^5-1}$

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
using
$x^n-1
=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{x^n-1}{x^m-1}
&=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k}{(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x^k}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x^k}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{n}{m}
\qquad\text{since }\lim_{x \to 1^-}x^k = 1\\
&=\frac{n}{m}\\
\end{array}
$

So, taking logs,
$\lim_{x \to 1^-}(\ln(x^n-1)-\ln(x^m-1))
=\ln(\frac{n}{m})
$.